# How do I use the adjacency matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, graph, adjacency-matrix

Hey I am new to programming and trying to store the following graph in an adjacency matrix

[image: graph]

I am not sure how to go about doing it. I want my code to read the graph information and store it in a data structure. From what I have learnt from YouTube videos so far is that I will need to make an adjacency structure in which I have the vertices (cities = 21) and edges (journeys = 43).

So far I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct value {
  int num;
  char start_vertex[250];
  char destination_vertex[250];
} value;

int main()
{
  const int nLines = 43; // number of lines in my text file
  FILE * fptr;
  //pointer to point to the first line as the next bit of code gets executed
  value * valuesPtr = malloc(sizeof(value) * nLines);

  if (!valuesPtr) {
    puts("cannot allocate memory");
    return -1;
  }

  if((fptr = fopen("energy.txt", "r")) == NULL)
  {
    perror("Error opening file");
    return -1;
  }
  int num[nLines];
  char start_vertex[nLines][250];
  char destination_vertex[nLines][250];

  for(int i = 0; i < nLines; i++ )
  {
      if (fscanf(fptr, "%249s %249s %d",
                 valuesPtr[i].start_vertex,
                 valuesPtr[i].destination_vertex,
                 &valuesPtr[i].num) != 3) {
        printf("errored file line %d\n", i);
        break;
      }

      num[i] = valuesPtr[i].num;
      strcpy(start_vertex[i], valuesPtr[i].start_vertex);
      strcpy(destination_vertex[i], valuesPtr[i].destination_vertex);

      printf("\nStart vertex: %s \nDestination vertex: %s \nWeight: %d\n\n",
             valuesPtr[i].start_vertex, valuesPtr[i].destination_vertex, valuesPtr[i].num);

      printf("\nStart vertex: %s \nDestination vertex: %s \nWeight: %d\n\n",
             start_vertex[i], destination_vertex[i], num[i]);
  }
  free(valuesPtr);
  fclose(fptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Can some one show me how I will go about doing it?

Comment: Identify each of the `n` vertices of the graph with one integer from the first `n` positive integers. Build a matrix `M=(m_ij), i=1..n, j=1..n`. Set element `m_ij` to `1` if and only if there is an edge from the graph node represented by `i` to the graph node represented by `j`. Set all other elements to 0. Find a `C` data structure for the matrix in `C` (eg. array of arrays). Note that 'adjacency matrix' != 'adjacency structure', the latter could be eg. linked lists of neighbor nodes. As the video does not seem to convey these basic insights, dump it (and its kin) in favor of a good textbook!

Comment: Is it possible if you could show me an example of it, just post that as an answer so I can go over it and visualise what you are trying to say

Comment: Just use a matrix of size n*n. Where n is the number of nodes matrix[u][v] will tell if you have a directed edge between u and v. You can set matrix[u][v] to 1 or the weight of the edge if the graph is weighted. If your graph is undirected set matrix[u][v] = 1 and matrix[v][u] = 1.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/ check this post for reference it should help you.

Comment: @Wasim Ahmad is it possible if I can see that in a code and could you comment the matrix size which I am assuming will be 21*21 since there are 21 nodes (cities). I saw a video of a person doing it on YouTube and they were using double pointers which I am not sure how to implement in the code unfortunately.

Comment: Perfect I which check that link now